# Influence of Levi-Civita identity in a Pauli matrix

Tags: tensor-calculus

Considering the following expansion of operators in SU(2) in commutators

$$[[V, \rho], V] = \left[\left[v_0 + \sum_{i=1}^3 v_i \sigma_i^3, \rho_0 + \sum_{j=1}^3 \rho_j \sigma_j\right], v_0 + \sum_{l=1}^3 v_l \sigma_l \right] = \sum_{i,j,l=1}^3 v_i \rho_j v_l [[\sigma_i,\sigma_j],\sigma_l]\tag{1}$$

So

$$[\sigma_i,\sigma_j] = 2i \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k \tag{2}$$

and

$$[[V, \rho], V] = (2i)^2\sum_{i,j,l=1}^3 v_i \rho_j v_l \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{klm}\sigma_m \tag{3}$$

There is a Levi-Civita identity of the type

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk} = \delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}.\tag{4}
\end{equation}
In my calculation I have a slightly different case, which is

$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\sigma_m,\tag{5}$$

Does the identity in (4) still hold in (5)?

Comment: How did you get an expression with three of an index? Such expressions are not proper.

Comment: Are you sure there are three $k$-indices in expression (2)?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the sigma index after your mention and edited the question specifying a little more my problem.

Comment: As (4) and (5) stand *now*, indeed, (4) may be inserted in (5). Observe how all antisymetries of (4) are realized.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "summation is implicit", but what that almost always means is that when you see an index appearing ***two*** times, there is summation over that index:

$$
\tag{1}
 c_i x^i = \sum_i c_ix_i
$$

In the case of your identity, we have:

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lm}^{~~~~~k} = \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk} = \epsilon_{ij1}\epsilon_{lm1} + \epsilon_{ij2}\epsilon_{lm2} + \ldots 
\end{equation}

The issue in your case is that you have a single index occurring three times in one term, and the convention above (which is quite universally used) is for two indices, not three.

Therefore you may wish to define what you mean by "summation is implicit" for the case where there's three copies of the same index occurring in one term.

Maybe you mean:

\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\sigma_k \equiv \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmk}\sigma_k = \epsilon_{ij1}\epsilon_{lm1}\sigma_1 + \epsilon_{ij2}\epsilon_{lm2}\sigma_2 + \ldots 
\end{equation}

In this case you cannot use your identity where you express the Levi-Civita symbols by Kronecker delta symbols, because the Pauli matrices are not all the same, so you can't factor out the $\sigma$'s in Eq. 3.

Comment: Sorry, the last sigma index was wrong. I specified my question a little bit more.

Comment: @Marcos What you have done is completely changed your question. I suggest you ask a new one. Your original question was not a typo, since you did ask specifically what happens to the $sigma_k$.